# Kill the screen lock and restore X session in XFCE

Tags: linux, xfce, lock-screen

I'm not big on graphical / windowed desktop environments and was using XFCE as a way to avoid clutter / having to deal with a lot of settings, but recently I ran into a problem: the lock screen program seems to have corrupted / incorrect credentials for my user.  As a result, whenever my screen locks, I have to restart the X session.

Just so you don't think I'm trying to break into someone else's computer: I have complete access to this computer anyways, it normally boots in multi-user mode.  So, I can just Ctrl+Alt+F# and log into a new session.  The biggest inconvenience about X session not unlocking is that I have to restore the browser tabs...

Is there any way I can tell XFCE to unlock the screen, not providing username / password?

Comment: Not sure how XFCE locks the screen, but with programs like `xlock` etc. you can just kill the program. So try `ps` and see if a good candidate shows up. This won't work if the WM itself locks the screen. Edit: [This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xfce) says XFCE runs a bash script and tries 4 screen lockers in turn. (But of course you could also edit this script to disable locking completely...)

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to disable locking (else, I'd have to carry my laptop around the office...). I'll try to figure out which of these screen lockers is being used. On the face of it, it should be `xlockmore`